# Do I have to change the baking time when I convert fahrenheit to Celsius?

Tags: baking, temperature, cookies, conversion

So in this recipe i should bake my cookies to 350 degrees F for 8 to 10 minutes.350 degrees fahrenheit is about 176 Celsius degrees and i dont know if I should change the baking time to more or less minutes.Anybody help me ?

Comment: You can think of it this way. If you had a dial set to 350F and you start baking, then someone decided to convert the temperatures shown on the dial to celsius by just placing a sticker over all the numbers. Now the dial is showing 176C with 350F hidden underneath. Whatever you are baking inside the oven would not know anything about the stick and would cook the same as before.

Comment: Yes, you need to convert to metric time.

Comment: Oh yes. @smithkm. Forgot about that part

Answer (score 15):

No. 350F is exactly the same as 176.66...C

Follow the recipe in exactly the same way

Answer (score 3):

An equivalent Celsius temperature would be 180. The precision with which oven temperatures are measured even in a well calibrated oven is larger than this rounding error (given that most oven temperatures are set with a dial and measured at a single arbitrary point). The difference in cooking time will be well within normal variation as you'd expect from things like ingredient temperature.